# How to manage my domains the right way on shared hosting?

Tags: iis-7, web-server, hosting, domain, web-hosting

I have a shared windows hosting account on godaddy, and i setup there 5 different websites on the same hosting space.

I am facing some problems and couldn't solve my self and godaddy can't give me a way to solve.

First these websites are in wordpress, community server, and graffiti CMS.

Problems:

1- all home pages for subdirectory website are like that "http://amrelgarhy.com/amrelgarhy/" so the name of the website exist 2 times in the URL, and this not happening in the root website "igurr.com"

2- Inner websites inheriting properties from the root one, such as the web.config.

3- I really don't know which to make in IIS7 as application root and which not.

4- If the solution is to put the root website in a subfolder like others, how to do this. "seams for me that godaddy not allowing that"

Please check the following screen shots for better understanding and advice me what to do.

http://screencast.com/t/TDUqDLsm

http://screencast.com/t/ZfDfmETQ

http://screencast.com/t/W9LkUmNKhnB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your domains accessible from their root names, each of your domains need to be root level (primary) sites. It seems to me that the account you have with go-daddy is for a single domain, that allows you to use additional domains for sub folders, this is not what you need.

You are probably going to need to upgrade your account, or go to another provider that will give you an account that will do what you want. You need to be looking at a multiple domain or reseller type account.